# Java Swing Timer infinite loop

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener, infinite-loop

I'm having an issue with a simple Java swing Timer I set. It does everything fine up until having to stop. I think it is creating an infinite loop of timers upon timers but I've been following multiple tutorials and I can't see where I have gone wrong.

Code explanation: The runButtonListener needs to loop through as many times as filelinecount variable says (read from a different function). The code at the moment is just printing to the system, I will have it updating some animations later. filelinecount is 0 in the code below, but gets changed by a different function. So for the sake of debugging, I think the attached code is runnable if you change the value of filelinecount manually.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
private int filelinecount = 0;
private int timercount = 0;
private Timer timer;

class runButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        // LOOK AT TIMER!!!
        if (timercount == filelinecount) {
            timer.stop();
            System.out.println("stopping");
            //timercount = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.println("yo " + timercount + "," + filelinecount);

            timercount++;
        }

        timer = new Timer(100,this);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time the timer calls you back you create a new timer and start it.

This includes after you call `timer.stop()`!

You need to only create the new timer if you want to continue.

Really you should look at another method for doing this rather than constantly recreating timers though. There are several methods available depending on your exact requirements.

For example using `scheduleAtFixedRate`, using a worker thread or `SwingWorker`, `ScheduledExecutorService`, etc.

Comment: Well I want it to loop as many times as the length of a file that it reads, so it's unknown until the file is read. How how I code it so it doesn't keep recreating timers? Should I changed the timer action to another function so it runs that function x times?

Comment: And why do you want a 100ms delay between each line? It sounds like you just want to use a SwingWorker here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: The 100ms delay is for later when it will be updating a GUI. I tried implementing Swingworking earlier but i couldn't quite understand how to apply it to my code (MVC architecture) and the posts i read all seemed to imply a swing timer as being easier to implement